# Table cell auto layout issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, xib

I have done dynamic table cell height increase when text changes. My both label are changing their sizes according to text but my cell height is not increasing.
I have given below constrains to all views:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

but I am getting output as below:

[image]

in out put you can see that I have given green color to my cell's background but its showing small area.please help me to solve this issue. I don't know where my constrains are wrong, also its not showing any constrained related error in console.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 mistakes I have done:
1) I have given botton labels bottom space constrains to "less than or equals " but it should be equal constrains
2) Also there were code side mistake : One must set cell's all values again in cell for row at index index path , which i have forgotten to do that

All above things solve my issue and my table cell is now resize according to text..

Comment: Be careful! It will resize according to text on iOS 8, but it won't do that on iOS 7 and prior. In order to make it work on iOS 7 you should implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, and calculate a required height manually, there must be questions on this topic on SO.